# pandas dataframe calculate squared distance between each 2 rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, heatmap

I have dataframe with numeric rows

```
Writer  |   A   |   B   |   C 
   1    |  0.2  |  0.4  |  0.6
   2    |  0.1  |  1.2  |  0.3
   3    |  0.5  |  0.2  |  0.8
```

I want to calculate squared distance between 2 writer.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want distances between all pairs, you can use `sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances`, as follows:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances

D = pairwise_distances (df [['A','B','C']].values)
```

If you want just the distance between two writers, say 1 and 2:

```py
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances

D_12 = euclidean_distances(df[['A','B','C']].values[0,:], df[['A','B','C']].values[1,:])
```